# Regex validation in Formula Field

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I have formula field textbox and Regex validation like below.

Formula Field Value :   `#1+#2+1-3*5/4*(5-1)`

I have validate the Formula Field by using below regex

```
_fieldRegex = new Regex("#(?<fieldId>[0-9]+)") and
_validateRegex = new Regex("^[()+-. \t0-9/*#]*$")
```

and it is working fine for me.

Now I encounter a scenario where I have to give value for formula field only like `#1+1` and not more than one Operation .

Can any one help me to validate this scenario by using Regex.

Comment: Just to be sure, you wish to verify that only a single mathematical operation is conducted? For example 15+90, 12/30002, 33*33 are all valid samples? Also, is the # significant?

Comment: @hSchroedl : Yes you are right. I need only the single operation.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. This regex should suffice for your needs:

```
^#\d+[+\-*\\]\d+$
```

A quick explanation:

- **^** signifies that we match from the start of a line.
- **\d+** signifies that we mach any digits, with cardinality one or more.
- **[+\-\\*]** is the list of possible operations, which you might want to extend. The extra slashes are there as some signs must be escaped.
- **$** signifies the end of the line.

For a more detailed explanation please have a look at one of the many regexp tutorials out there. I hope this helps.